# Removing blank spaces in Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, trim

I am not able to remove blank spaces from a Hive table.

Below is the input:

```
select ColName from <TableName> where <Filtering Condition>;
EAIaIQobChMIibKXn4HY3QIVieNkCh2vxwlQEAQYByABEgIGRfD_BwE

select hex("EAIaIQobChMIibKXn4HY3QIVieNkCh2vxwlQEAQYByABEgIGRfD_BwE");
4541496149516F6243684D4969624B586E3448593351495669654E6B4368327678776C514541515942794142456749475266445F427745
```

Below are the way I tried to remove Blank space:

```
select hex(ColName) from <TableName> where <Filtering Condition>;

select hex(trim(ColName)) from <TableName> 
where <Filtering Condition>;

select hex(REGEXP_REPLACE(ColName, '\\s+', '')) from <TableName>  where <Filtering Condition>;

select hex(translate(ColName, ' ', '')) from <TableName>  where <Filtering Condition>;

select hex(regexp_replace(trim(ColName),' +',' ')) from <TableName>  where <Filtering Condition>;
```

Here is the output for all able queries:

```
004500410049006100490051006F006200430068004D004900690062004B0058006E003400480059003300510049005600690065004E006B004300680032007600780077006C0051004500410051005900420079004100420045006700490047005200660044005F00420077004500
```

Tried below also. But no luck:

```
select regexp_replace(ColName,'\\s','');
select regexp_replace(ColName,'\\p{Blank}','');
select regexp_replace(ColName,'\\p{Space}','');
select regexp_replace(ColName,'\\p{javaWhitespace}','');
```

I just used hex in most of the cases to identify the spaces. From above output I clearly understand that none of the queries are removing the spaces as 00 is getting prefixed for all the characters.

Is there any other way to fix my issue?

My problem statement is I am trying to join this string between two tables. But due to blank spaces in one of the table I am not getting matches.

Comment: Hi All, I figured out the issue. Issue is with input file format. Reloaded table by converting input file to UTF-8 using "iconv --from-code="UCS-2LE" --to-code=UTF-8 ip.csv >  op1.csv".  Now its working fine. Thanks